"single" command line argument which contains spaces is getting treated as multiple arguments
In godbolt compiler explorer (https://godbolt.org/z/Gqc5PeKz8) I am passing a single argument which contains spaces inside quotes, but it looks they are getting treated as separate arguments:
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    std::cout << argc << ", " << argv[1] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

Execution Arguments:
"a b c"

Output:
4, "a

I tried various options like single quote, double quote and putting a special symbol(\) before space.

This looks like a bug in compiler explorer more than anything else. Your program works correctly on my machine.

Having a rapid look on the github of compiler-explorer, one can find this.executionArguments.split(' ') in file executor.ts, so it seems that the input args string will be split even if it is quoted hoping it will be taken as a single arg.

A work around might be to use "," instead of the spaces, and then later replace all "," with spaces again if needed.

raise an issue https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/issues

created an issue https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/issues/7083
